# How to get UE4 to correctly put my bundle identifier for iOS projects?

Tags: unreal-4

Each time I create a new project UE4 adds a generic bundle identifier to the iOS platform settings, that I always have to change to `com.myname.[PROJECT_NAME]` in order to be able to run the newly created project. So, I wonder how can I make UE4 to correctly auto detect this field from the picked provisioning profile.

I was thinking something like putting `[BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER]` (including the square brackets) but the editor crashes when I put that in the bundle identifier field.